# Aggregation in Postgres for finding last value

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a single table in postgres which holds aggregated data, the tables has the following fields

search_term --> a particular search term
date --> a date when the search has been performed
search_count --> how many times search has been performed with this search term
min_result_count --> what was the minimum number of result returned by the search term
max_results_count --> what was the maximum number of result returned by the search term
last_result_count --> number of search result returned when last search was performed
zero_result_count --> how mnay times there was no result for this search term

where **date** and **search_term** combination is unique, meaning search term won't be repeated for the date rather the value would be updated.

I am trying to write a sql query for the duration of 7 days to get the following record
search_term
min_result_count
max_result_count
zero_result_count
last_result_count

I could find all the values using the aggregation MIN, MAX, SUM but I am unable to find the value for the last_result_count since this would require me to pick up the last value only.

Here is one same table with expected result

```
search_term    search_count    min_rc    max_rc    zero_count    last_rc    date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
term1          10              10        20        0              4        01-01-2020
term1          10              11        21        0              5        02-01-2020
term1          10              12        22        0              6        03-01-2020
term1          10              13        23        0              7        04-01-2020
term1          10              14        24        0              8        05-01-2020

term2          10              24        25        0              9        01-01-2020
term2          10              23        26        0              10       02-01-2020
term2          10              22        27        0              11       03-01-2020
term2          10              21        28        0              12       04-01-2020
term2          10              0         29        3              0        04-01-2020
```

if I run the query 05-01-2020, I should get

```
search_term    search_count    min_rc    max_rc    zero_count    last_rc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
term1          50              10        24        0              8      
term2          50              0         29        3              0
```

if I run the query 04-01-2020, I should get

```
search_term    search_count    min_rc    max_rc    zero_count    last_rc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
term1          40              10        23        0              7      
term2          40              21        28        0              12
```

if I run the query 03-01-2020, I should get

```
search_term    search_count    min_rc    max_rc    zero_count    last_rc
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
term1          30              10        23        0              6      
term2          30              22        27        0              11
```

- rc stands for result_count

and so on, any help to derive last_result_count would be really helpful

Comment: I'm not super sure about how you are sourcing the lat_count column, but SQL analytics function LAG should solve the problem..

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-lag-function/

Comment: I am receiving the data from another system everyday, it gives me the aggregated result per day based on search term

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) window function for this. `ROW_NUMBER` orders your data with your inted then generates a number.

```
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY date,search_term ORDER BY LAST_RC) AS ROW_NUMBERED_COLUMN
```

You can then group your data and use `MAX(ROW_NUMBERED_COLUMN)`

Comment: we are grouping by search_term I can't use last_rc inside OVER since it's not part of group by

Answer (score 0):

You could use [window_functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) like below.

```
Select search_term ,
SUM(search_count) OVER (partition by search_term order BY date)  as search_count,
MIN(min_rc) OVER (partition by search_term order BY date)  as min_rc,
MAX(max_rc) OVER (partition by search_term order BY date)  as max_rc,
zero_count,
last_rc , 
DATE 
from t
ORDER BY search_term,date
```

Result set :

```
search_term    search_count    min_rc    max_rc    zero_count    last_rc   date
term1          10              10        20         0              4       01-01-2020
term1          20              10        21         0              5       02-01-2020
term1          30              10        22         0              6       03-01-2020
term1          40              10        23         0              7       04-01-2020
term1          50              10        24         0              8       05-01-2020
term2          10              24        25         0              9       01-01-2020
term2          20              23        26         0              10      02-01-2020
term2          30              22        27         0              11      03-01-2020
term2          50              0         29         0              12      04-01-2020
term2          50              0         29         3              0       04-01-2020
```

updated version*

```
SELECT search_term,search_count, min_rc, max_rc, zero_count, last_rc
FROM
(SELECT search_term ,
        SUM(search_count) OVER (partition by search_term order BY date) as search_count,
        MIN(min_rc) OVER (partition by search_term order BY date) as min_rc,
        MAX(max_rc) OVER (partition by search_term order BY date) as max_rc,
        zero_count,
        last_rc,
        RANK() OVER (partition by search_term order BY date desc) as rnk,
        date
 FROM t
 WHERE date <= '05-01-2020'
 ) A 
 WHERE A.rnk = 1
```

Another method which is simpler and I realized what you wanted after your comment.

```
SELECT search_term ,
SUM(search_count) as search_count,
MIN(min_rc) as min_rc,
MAX(max_rc) as max_rc,
SUM(zero_count) as zero_count,
(SELECT last_rc FROM t as a WHERE a.search_term = t.search_term AND a.date = 
 t.date ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 1) AS last_rc,
MAX(date) as date
FROM t
WHERE date <= '05-01-2020'
GROUP BY search_term
ORDER BY search_term
```

This is even more simple using window function last_value

```
Select search_term ,
SUM(search_count) as search_count,
MIN(min_rc) as min_rc,
MAX(max_rc) as max_rc,
SUM(zero_count) as zero_count,
LAST_VALUE(last_rc) OVER (Partition by search_term ORDER BY date desc) AS last_rc,
MAX(date) as date
FROM t
WHERE date <= '03-01-2020'
GROUP BY search_term
ORDER BY search_term
```

Result set using any of the updated versions.

```
search_term search_count    min_rc  max_rc  zero_count  last_rc
term1       50              10      24      0           8
term2       50              0       29      3           0
```

Comment: how can I use last_rc when the same is not a part of my group by clause ... here we are grouping by search_term, search_date ... I don't want my search_term to appear again and again, it should be distinct

Comment: check my edited answer for result set based on your sample data.

Comment: the terms should not be repeated as we are aggregating for 7d, there should be only two records term1 and term2, getting daily result is easy I want to know if we are aggregating for a week how should we catch hold of the last record in the last_rc column and show it as last_rc, refer to my resultset in the main post

Comment: check the updated version. You could use rank for latest record of last_rc